# Having problems setting up Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, exit-code, elk

I've succesfully been able to set up Elasticsearch, Kibana etc and when I run: 'sudo systemctl status elasticsearch' it is all running fine.

However, when I execute 'sudo systemctl status logstash' this is the output:

[image: Logstash Error]

It fails to start logstash, I've read numerous articles online saying it's something to do with path or config perhaps but I've had no luck finding a correct working solution.

I have JDK downloaded and followed the guide on the logstash documentation site so I'm unsure to as why logstash is not being allowed to run.

This is the output when I try to find out the logstash version.

[image: Logstash Version]

[image: Logstash Journal Output]

Comment: Can you run this and paste the output you get: `journalctl -u logstash`

Comment: @Val I just posted a screenshot of the output in the post, thanks

Comment: Thanks, but it's too small and the end of lines are cut

Comment: @Val Sorry I just updated it, hope this helps!

Comment: Actually you don't have any pipeline configuration: `No configuration found in the configured sources`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is

> No configuration found in the configured sources

This means that you don't have any pipeline configuration in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` that Logstash can run, so it stops.

Comment: I have another pipeline I'm using, it's currently stored in the home user area.

Comment: You need to move it to`/etc/logstash/conf.d`

Answer (score 0):

run logstash, logstash will read pipelines.yml to find your conf location

1. Logstash will find your `.conf` file from **pipelines.yml**. By default it will looking at `/etc/logstash/conf.d/` as **pipelines.yml** show.
   You have to move your configuration file to the path so logstash could find it.
2. or you want to run with specified file with it will ignore the **pipeline.yml** so logstash will directly go into your `.conf`
   `/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f yourconf.conf`

I will suggest you to do 1. but 2 is good for debugging your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying your suggested number 2 now using that command but I am receiving an error now saying 'No config files found in path {:path=>"/conf.conf"}. No configuration found in the configured sources. Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Comment: you have to run this in the same directory as your conf file. Try ``ls`` does your .conf file is there? If it is, then run ``/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f yourconf.conf``. Please let me know the process